# What can cause SetupDiGetClassDevs to return no device interfaces? (Windows, C++)

Tags: c++, windows, unity-game-engine, usb, hid

I've been working on this issue for over a month now.

What am I trying to do:
Get a list of HID devices attached to the system without failure.

What's happening:
SetupDiGetClassDevs is intermittently returning no devices (when filtered for HID devices), but only for the specific process in question. Other processes running simultaneously running the same calls work perfectly. I cannot reproduce this issue in a clean project no matter how hard I try.

Background:
I'm the author of an input system that runs under Unity 3D (game engine). A customer of mine is having problems with joystick hot plugging in his (gigantic) project. On the title screen of his game, everything works swimmingly. Once the first game level is loaded, Windows intermittently (and seemingly randomly) reports zero HID devices. As long as the current controller is still attached, input works fine, but during these periods of "failure", if the controller is removed and plugged back in, Windows returns 0 device interfaces.

I do not have access to this customer's project (over 80 GB), but have injected my own testing code into the executable to try to find the source of the problem. I have over a thousand customers and only this project seems to have this issue.

Here is some testing code I'm using in a C++ DLL to query the number of HID devices in the system.

```
int EnumerateDevices() {

int deviceCount = 0;

LPGUID guid = (LPGUID)malloc(sizeof(GUID));
HidD_GetHidGuid(guid);

HDEVINFO deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

if (deviceInfoSet != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

    SP_DEVINFO_DATA* deviceInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
    deviceInfoData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
    deviceInfoData->DevInst = 0;

    DWORD deviceIndex = 0;
    int totalDeviceCount = 0;
    int totalInterfaceCount = 0;

    while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, deviceIndex, deviceInfoData)) {
        deviceIndex += 1;

        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA* deviceInterfaceData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
        deviceInterfaceData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
        int deviceInterfaceIndex = 0;

        while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(deviceInfoSet, deviceInfoData, guid, deviceInterfaceIndex, deviceInterfaceData)) {
            deviceInterfaceIndex++;
            deviceCount++;
            totalInterfaceCount++;
        }

        totalDeviceCount++;
    }
    stringstream ssss;

    if(deviceIndex == 0) {
        ssss << "No devices. Last error = " << GetLastError() << "/n";
    }


    ssss << "Total Device Count = " << totalDeviceCount << " Total Interface Count = " << totalInterfaceCount;
    Log(ssss.str());

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoSet);
    delete(deviceInfoData);
} else {
    stringstream sss;
    sss << "Invalid handle value!";
    Log(sss.str());
}

free(guid);

return deviceCount;
```

}

The result is always OK with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE never returned. However during certain periods, Windows reports the number of devices as 0. SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo returns false and the error code is 259 (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS).

Unity is C# based, so I've tried both calling this function every frame from managed code and by spinning up a new thread in the C++ DLL and logging the results. Regardless, every time without fail, during the long load of the first level, devices reported will become 0. And intermittently throughout gameplay, the result will alternate between 6 (the number of total devices in the system) and 0. Sometimes the 0 result can stick for minutes at a time, and sometimes it will only happen for one frame.

What makes this problem even more interesting is XInput and Direct Input also will fail at exactly the same times as this code. XInput and DI are self-contained, but I suspect internally they are making the same Windows function calls. Clearly this issue is not in my code, but I have no idea what could possibly cause this kind of occurrence. I suspect some other plugin is interfering or possibly a lack of memory issue.

Other info:
If I change the call to SetupDiGetClassDevs to:

```
HDEVINFO deviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
```

I get a valid result return at all times -- 168. This never varies. None of these are device interfaces however, so I can't use this information. If I add back the device interface filters, I get 0 intermittently. Again, this only happens after a large level has been loaded and the game's memory footprint is over 2GB. I have read some issues with Direct Input and running out of heap memory causing it to return a result of OK but with no devices, but as far as I can tell there's no relationship between memory and this issue (except for that fact that it NEVER occurs on the title screen when memory is ~500MB, only after the level loads past 1.6GB or so do you start seeing it -- but again, I have no access to the project to determine if it's some plugin/component in there causing this.)

Just to re-state:
If I run a parallel process (another instance of Unity using a different project) simultaneously and watch the logs, I receive the correct value of 6 devices at all times at the very same moment this process returns 0. This same behavior is consistent with Windows HID functions, Direct Input, and XInput. When one fails, all fail. Yet the other processes running simultaneously NEVER have a problem seeing all the devices every frame.

Unity is based on an ancient version of Mono, so I imagine there could be issues there, but my attempt to circumvent the issues of Mono by spinning up a native thread to do the testing show that it doesn't really make any difference.

Having worked on this so long, I've scoured the web for information but can't find anything that remotely resembles this issue.

Edit: Forgot to mention, this project uses Steam also.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to force the MS code to allocate memory below 0x80000000 by allocating our discardable heap above 0x80000000, if your program is running on a 64 bit os.